# Using declarative だ with negative i-adjectives

Tags: grammar

I am complete beginner and I've got a question that I wish to ask you: When negating an i-adjective (-くない), should we, as in the affirmative form, omit the declarative "だ"? For example, is it "あのゲームは楽しくないだよ！" or "あのゲームは楽しくないよ！".

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are a complete beginner, this is probably not relevant to you, but to anyone else who may come across this question, it is worth mentioning that there are some dialects which allow だ after i-adjectives, such as 遠州弁 or 三河弁.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot attach a 「だ」 directly to an i-adjective, either in its affirmative or negative form.  (But believe me, many Japanese-learners make this mistake.)

> Incorrect: 「[楽]{たの}しいだ」、「楽しくないだ」、「[大]{おお}きいだ」、「大きくないだ」, etc.

Attaching a よ or ね is correct and very natural --- affirmative or negative.

> Correct: 「楽しいね」、「大きくないよ」、「かわいいね」、「おいしくないよ」, etc.

If you absolutely MUST use a だ for some reason, you can do so by inserting a 「の」　or informally, a　「ん」 between the i-adjective and the 「だ」 --- affirmative or negative.

> Correct: 「楽しいのだ」、「[小]{ちい}さいんだ」、「[高]{たか}いんだ」、「[赤]{あか}いのだ」、「かわいくないのだ」、「大きくないんだ」, etc.

Comment: I do know that we musn't use "da" with an i-adjective when it is in its affirmative form, but I was wondering about the negative form. 

So thanks for your answer, it sure clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

When negating an i-adjective, you change い for くない. The ない part is an auxiliary i-adjective, so you should omit だ, just as you do for i-adjectives.

> 新幹線は速い。
> A bullet train is fast.
>
> 壊れた新幹線は速くない。
> A broken bullet train is not fast.

Comment: I would personally say だ was never there in the first place, rather than say that it's omitted.

Comment: Sure, but the question body said "should I omit it?", so I chose to use the same language.